# Trying to understand structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to Apache spark and trying to understand structured streaming with Apache kafka in scala but nothing worked in my favour till now basically I want to send JSON from kafka process it using spark structured streaming and send back to kafka. I tried the example given on the website but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}
object dataset_kafka {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("kafka-consumer")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
      .option("subscribe", "test")
      .load()

       df
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
      .option("topic", "test1")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/hduser/Desktop/tempo")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Any help with where am I going wrong?

I am sending json from kafka in this format:

```
{"schema":"Hiren","payload":"123"}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  See here on how to post a good question, one that is likely not to be closed, and perhaps even answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is my question invalid ?

Comment: You are expected to show some code of your own that is not working / some effort of your own. What you are asking for is called a tutorial

Comment: Sir as you said i tried on my own but it is not working , please help me to correct my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I recently published an anthology of technical assets focused on Apache Spark's Structured Streaming. One of the blogs focuses on Structured Streaming: that is, streaming your data out from Kafka and into Spark, using Structured Streaming APIs.

I would urge for you to peek at it. Note that writing back to Kafka is only supported in Spark 2.2.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/24/anthology-of-technical-assets-on-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html